# Focus a buffer window if already visible; open a window with the buffer if not

Tags: buffers, focus, visibility, treemacs

I'd like to use a single function (and later keybind it to a single key) that would do the following:

- if treemacs is visible in the frame, focus to its window;
- if not, call `treemacs`.

I took a look at `window-buffer` and `get-buffer-window`, however it's not clear how would I utilize those functions: I don't have a buffer in a variable to start with, and programmatically predicting a treemacs buffer name kinda seems like an non-trivial task (`buffer-name` gives me something like `" *Treemacs-Scoped-Buffer-#<framec *scratch* (projectile-project) - GNU Emacs at HOST 0x555ed35d4cc8>*"`).

Do I have to loop through all the visible windows, get displayed buffer names and match them against " *Treemacs-Scoped-Buffer" instead? Is there a better way, say a treemacs specific `treemacs-visible-p` that would tell me the info I need? Or do I approach the problem incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `treemacs-select-window` may do what you are looking for.

From treemacs.el:

```
(treemacs-select-window)

Select the treemacs window if it is visible.
Bring it to the foreground if it is not visible.
Initialise a new treemacs buffer as calling ‘treemacs’ would if there is no
treemacs buffer for this frame.
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!